# Visual studio faild to build docker image with error CTC-1014

Tags: docker, dockerfile, visual-studio-2019

I have been using docker desktop and docker build without any issue on my home network, but on my office network i am  unable to create a docker images with error **"CTC1014" Proxy authentication required** error. Office network uses a proxy server to communicate to external network using windows credentials and forefront tmg client. I have used almost every combination of proxy but nothing worked. Here is what i tried.

1-Tried proxy address on docker desktop as https://myproxy.com:8080

2-Tried proxy address as https://username:password@myproxy.com:8080

3-Tried proxy address as https://username:urlencodedpassword@myproxy.com:8080

4-Tried adding ARG HTTP_PROXY="http://username:urlencodedpassword@myproxy.com:8080 in my docker file.

5- Tried adding proxy setting in **devenv.exe.config** for visual studio.

I have also tried 2 different version of docker i.e. docker-4.10.1 and 4.17.0, the version 4.17.0 always keeps asking for proxy username and password again and again and nothing works but 4.10.1 never asks for username and password and neither it works.

Here is complete error from visual studio.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CTC1014 Docker command failed with exit code 1.
#1 [internal] load build definition from dockerfile
#1 sha256:6fb6c82191b12da8df4c262bce9667faefc40e3725c4dfc959aebca686b935e8
#1 transferring dockerfile: 1.23kB 0.0s done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 sha256:304880e25345d6cb2af2bbadb00d5e909c5e811846e49e80a62952674d89978a
#2 transferring context: 35B 0.0s done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim
#3 sha256:c649b8985fea718a60b662fe79b91a725ab3e4c4764967511892d006b7b28ba0
#3 CANCELED

#4 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim
#4 sha256:f3abb15cd48f1bf7d482810f16c4d2f5442172e86b1a2317ec3e041de068b455
#4 ERROR: failed to do request: Head "https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/dotnet/aspnet/manifests/5.0-buster-slim": Proxy Authentication Required
------
 > [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head "https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/dotnet/aspnet/manifests/5.0-buster-slim": Proxy Authentication Required  myapp.Myapp.Misc    d:\projects\myapp.myapp.microservices\myapp.mymyapp.misc\dockerfile 1
```